# Assistance with tabular arrays and ints in other methods

Tags: java, arrays, int

Hi i am writing the following program for my java class and i cannot figure out why  my array wont work also how to make the ints count up even though they are in different classes if thats not possible thats fine but what are some different methods of doing this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    //char{}{} Vote = {{President, Karl Karlington, Bob Mcbob, Nope Noper},{Vice President, Not Optiono, Hap Pinino, Rad ish},{Person, Not Person, Also Person, Person Person}}; 

    System.out.print("Welcome to voteathon 10,000!!\n");
    System.out.print("We will be displaying the canidates shortly\n");
    //display(Vote);
    PresVote(Nope, Bob, Karl);
    VPresVote(Not, Hap, Rad);
    PersonVote(NotP, AlsoP, Person);

    System.out.printf("For president Karl had: %d Bob had: %d Nope had: %d \n", Karl, Bob, Nope);
    System.out.printf("For vice president Not had: %d Hap had: %d Rad had: %d \n", Not, Hap, Rad);
    System.out.printf("For person Not had: %d Also had: %d Person had: %d \n", NotP, AlsoP, Person);

    }
public static void display(int x[][]){
    for(int row=0;row<4;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<x[row] .length;column++){
            System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void PresVote(int Nope, int Bob, int Karl){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("To vote please enter 1 2 or 3 corresponding to the table above\n");
    System.out.print("vote: ");
    int A = input.nextInt();

    if (A == 1){
        System.out.print("\nYou voted for Karl!\n");
        Karl++;

    }
    else if(A == 2){
        System.out.print("You voted for Bob!\n");
        Bob++;
       }
    else if (A == 3){
        System.out.print("You voted for Nope!\n");
        Nope++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("No vote invalid answer\n");
    }
}
    public static void VPresVote(int Not, int Hap, int Rad){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("To vote please enter 1 2 or 3 corresponding to the table above ");
    System.out.print("\n vote: \n");
    int A = input.nextInt();

    if (A == 1){
        System.out.print("You voted for Not!\n");
        Not++;

    }
    else if(A == 2){
        System.out.print("You voted for Hap!\n");
        Hap++;
       }
    else if (A == 3){
        System.out.print("You voted for Rad!\n");
        Rad++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("No vote invalid answer\n");
    }
}
    public static void PersonVote(int NotP, int AlsoP, int Person){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("To vote please enter 1 2 or 3 corresponding to the table above ");
    System.out.print("\n vote: \n");
    int A = input.nextInt();

    if (A == 1){
        System.out.print("You voted for Not!\n");
        NotP++;

    }
    else if(A == 2){
        System.out.print("You voted for Also!\n");
        AlsoP++;
       }
    else if (A == 3){
        System.out.print("You voted for Person!\n");
        Person++;
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("No vote invalid answer\n");
    }
}
```

I intialized the ints prior but i dont know if that does anything

Comment: With your current code you will need to return the `int` variables from the methods `primitive` values are immutable

Comment: @ScaryWombat How do i return the ints?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the passed in arguments. The arguments in this case local variables do not have global scope, so they don't hold the execution information like increment in this case when the function call is returned.

Instead pass an array like this for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int[] president = new int[3]; //president[0] indicates 'x',president[2] say 'z' 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("To vote please enter 1 2 or 3 corresponding to the table above\n");
    System.out.print("vote: ");
    int A = input.nextInt();
    presVote(president, A);
    // rest of code
}
public static void presVote(int[] president, int A) {
    if(A == 1) {
        president[0]++; // vote count of 'x' increases by 1
    }
    // similar conditionals for other input
}
```

By this way the president array would have vote count.

or other way would be maintain static int variable for storing vote counts for individual.